# KQL from any row that has "name" word in it

Tags: kql

I try to do something like this:

```
union *| where *IP* contains "192" and TimeGenerated > ago(90d)3
```

What I want to achieve is to search on any row that contains the "IP" on its name.
Do you have any suggestions?
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: So you are looking to search a column with name IP for specific value?  Question needs to be clearer and what you have tried.  What does your table look like?

Comment: yes, this what I try to do.

Comment: SELECT * FROM YOURTABLENAME WHERE IP LIKE '%192%' will show all ip's with 192 in them.

Comment: are you sure that its runs with KQL?

Comment: I was not sure that was what you were using in which case I don't think it will I have not used KQL before so could not recognize syntax.

Comment: If the answer below helped, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you still need clarifications, please add a comment describing what you need, and we'll help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
TableName
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| where IP contains "192"
```

Comment: I need to search on any table name that contains IP.

Comment: For this you'll need to use the `search` operator (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator#summary-of-string-matching-extensions)) or the `find` operator (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/findoperator#examples)).